# insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database: Error with id_column

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, compact-framework

I'm trying to figure out how do multiple insert in sqlite3 database according this answer

[Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

It seems to work perfectly, but I have a problem: my table has 9 columns + the usual ID that is "primary key autoincrement not null"...a total of 10 columns.

If I use the statement indicated in above topic, it works only if I specify an ID.

If I omit the ID in the statement, it gives me error "SQLite error table Weights has 10 columns but 9 values were supplied"

If I do a single insert and I omit the ID of course it gives the next default value automatically.

How can I omit the ID for this multiple insert?

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm programming on a compact framework 3.5 on Windows CE 6.

Thank you

```
'DATABASE WEIGHT COLUMNS NAME
Private Const DBWGTIdLotto = "IDLotto"
Private Const DBWGTProgressive = "ProgressiveNum"
Private Const DBWGTWeight = "Weight"
Private Const DBWGTTime = "theTime"
Private Const DBWGTStatusFlag = "StatusFlag"
Private Const DBWGTTot1 = "Tot1"
Private Const DBWGTTot2 = "Tot2"
Private Const DBWGTTot3 = "Tot3"
Private Const DBWGTPrice = "Price"

'CREATE THE DATABASE
Public Sub CreateDatabaseWeights()
    Try
        If Not File.Exists(Me.DatabasePesatePath) Then
            'Crea la tabella
            Dim sqlString As String = "CREATE TABLE " + DatabasePesateTableName + "(" _
                                    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " _
                                    + DBWGTIdLotto + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " _
                                    + DBWGTProgressive + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " _
                                    + DBWGTWeight + " INTEGER, " _
                                    + DBWGTTime + " TIMESTAMP, " _
                                    + DBWGTStatusFlag + " INTEGER, " _
                                    + DBWGTTot1 + " BOOLEAN, " _
                                    + DBWGTTot2 + " BOOLEAN, " _
                                    + DBWGTTot3 + " BOOLEAN, " _
                                    + DBWGTPrice + " REAL" _
                                    + ");"
            Dim db As New SQLiteDatabase(Me.DatabasePesatePath)
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlString)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiErrore("CLASS: RecordPeso => CreateDatabaseWeights: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

'SUB TO INSERT MULTIPLE RECORDS
Public Sub AggiungiPeso(ByVal lotto As Integer, ByVal progressive As Integer, ByVal weight As Integer, ByVal flag As Byte, ByVal tot1 As Boolean, ByVal tot2 As Boolean, ByVal tot3 As Boolean, ByVal price As Single)
    Try


        Dim test(100) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For i As Integer = test.GetLowerBound(0) To test.GetUpperBound(0)
            'Crea il dizionario con i valori
            Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            data.Add("id", i.ToString) 'IF I REMOVE THIS, IT GIVES ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            data.Add(DBWGTIdLotto, lotto.ToString)
            data.Add(DBWGTProgressive, progressive.ToString)
            data.Add(DBWGTWeight, weight.ToString)
            data.Add(DBWGTTime, Now.ToString)
            data.Add(DBWGTStatusFlag, flag.ToString)
            data.Add(DBWGTTot1, IIf(tot1, "1", "0"))
            data.Add(DBWGTTot2, IIf(tot2, "1", "0"))
            data.Add(DBWGTTot3, IIf(tot3, "1", "0"))
            data.Add(DBWGTPrice, price.ToString)
            test(i) = Data
        Next

        'Salva il nuovo peso
        Dim db As New SQLiteDatabase(Me.DatabasePesatePath)
        db.MultipleInsert(DatabasePesateTableName, test)
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiErrore("CLASS: RecordPeso => AggiungiPeso: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

--------------- DATABASE CLASS --------------------

'Insert a row in the database
'<tableName>    Nome della tabella
'<data()>       Array di Dizionari con coppie di colonne/valori
'<return>       Boolean per successo o fallimento
Public Function MultipleInsert(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal data() As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As Boolean
    Dim vals As String = ""
    Dim columns As String = ""
    Dim returnCode As Boolean = True
    Try
        'Se abbiamo elementi
        If data.Count >= 1 And data(0).Count >= 1 Then
            Dim tmpQuery As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} SELECT ", tableName)
            'Creo la query per l'aggiornamento
            For Each val As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In data(0)
                tmpQuery += String.Format("'{0}' AS '{1}', ", val.Value.ToString, val.Key.ToString)
            Next
            'Remove last useless comma
            tmpQuery = tmpQuery.Substring(0, tmpQuery.Length - 2)
            'Aggiorno tutti i valori degli altri dizionari
            For i As Integer = data.GetLowerBound(0) + 1 To data.GetUpperBound(0)
                'Contatore inizio riga
                Dim j As Integer = 0
                'Add value of other dictionaries
                For Each Val As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In data(i)
                    If j = 0 Then tmpQuery += " UNION SELECT"
                    tmpQuery += String.Format(" '{0}',", Val.Value.ToString)
                    j += 1
                Next
                tmpQuery = tmpQuery.Substring(0, tmpQuery.Length - 1)
                j = 0
            Next
            'Aggiorna il DB
            Me.ExecuteNonQuery(tmpQuery)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiRigaSuFile(ErroriPath, "CLASS: SQLiteDatabase => MultipleInsert: " + ex.Message, True, True)
        returnCode = False
    End Try
    Return returnCode
End Function

'Interact with database for purpose different from query
'<sqlString>    SQL string for interacting in DB
'<return>       Number of columns updated
Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal sqlString As String) As Integer
    Dim rowsUpdated As Integer = 0
    Try
        'Definisco la connessione al database
        Using cnn As New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
            cnn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
            cmd.CommandText = sqlString
            'Aggiorno i dati
            rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiRigaSuFile(ErroriPath, "CLASS: SQLiteDatabase => ExecuteNonQuery: " + ex.Message, True, True)
    End Try
    'Ritorna le righe elaborate
    Return rowsUpdated
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds a whole lot like you don't actually have AUTOINCREMENT set on the PK field.

Comment: here you are the codes, I pasted relevant subs...hope to haven't done mistakes in the process.

@ctacke: if I wouldn't have autoincrement...how can I do a single insert without specifying ID ?

Answer (score 0):

do not include the id column name in the first set of parenthesis.
then also do not include any value for it in the values part.

Comment: If I don't include the ID, it gives me error "SQLite error table Weights has 10 columns but 9 values were supplied"

Comment: then you identified 10 columns in the first list... which you shouldn't.

Comment: why Should I declare only 9? I want the usual ID and If I omit it, I will not find in the table.